# QT context menu not aligned with cursor

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, contextmenu, qlistwidget

When I right click, a context menu appears but it is not aligned with the cursor. I want the corner of the context menu to appear right where the cursor is. Here you can see it is quite far off to the right:

[image]

Here is the method where the context menu is shown:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{

    QMenu menu("contextMenu", this);
    QAction deleteItem("Delete", this);
    menu.addAction(&deleteItem);
    connect(&deleteItem, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(deleteItem()));
    menu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos)); 

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pos` variable is relative to the `viewport()` of the `QListWidget` so you must use the `mapToGlobal()` method of the `QListWidget`:

```cpp
menu.exec(ui->listWidget->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
```